# How to display data in javascript using SPARQL

Tags: javascript, html, sparql, dbpedia

:) Hello everyone

I have a little problem there, I'm currently trying to work on Linked open data and for that, I have to do a small website which could display the informations of my choice.
        The thing is that i don't know how to display the datas using javascript...
        Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/jquery.sparql.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/encode.js"></script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>Manga project - Mangas and anime directory</title>


  <meta name="description" content= "directory on Manga project : manga or anime actuality, multimedia, J-Music, asian culture, video games, fans and autors..." />
  <meta name="keywords" content="Manga, anime, video manga, animated manga, directory" />
  <meta name="google" content="nositelinkssearchbox">




  <!-- Facebook Meta Tags -->
  <meta property="og:title" content="Manga Project">
  <meta property="og:url" content="#">
  <meta property="og:description" content="directory on Manga project : manga or anime actuality, multimedia, J-Music, asian culture, video games, fans and autors...">
  <meta property="og:image" content="petitIcone.png">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="manga-news.com">
  <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
  <!-- Twitter Cards -->
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
  <meta name="twitter:image:src" content="petitIcone.png">
  <meta name="twitter:site" content="@manga_project">
  <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@manga_project">
  <meta name="twitter:domain" content="#">
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="Manga Projet - Manga and anime directory">
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="Directory on Manga-project : Actuality about manga, anime, multimedia, J-music, asian culture, videogames and authors...">



  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="mn144.png">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ff7c00">


  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css" type="text/css" media="projection, screen"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-2575586-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowAnchor', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
  window.___gcfg = {lang: 'fr'};

  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
</head>


<body style="background-color:#3c5977;">

  <header class="headroom">

<div id="header_top">

<div class="container">

      <div id="logo">
      <a href="accueil.html" title="Mangas - Annuaire manga..">
        <img src="test.gif" alt="manga" width="279" height="43"/><span>Manga project</span></a>
    </div>








  <div id="topsearch">
    <form id="search-form" action="index.php/recherche/" method="get">
      <input type="text" value="Search" id="q_search" name="q" alt="chercher"/>
      <input type="submit" class="submit" id="searchMain" value=""/>
    </form>
  </div>





  <div class="clear"></div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
</div><!-- /#header_top -->

<div id="header_bottom">

<div class="container">

  <div id="blockmenu">

    <nav>

     <ul>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a id="menuHomepage" href="../accueil.html" class="actu" title="Actu">Homepage</a>


    </li>


    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#  " class="livremenu" title="Mangas">Mangas</a>

    <div class="drop-menu" role="menu">
        <div class="block-1-3">
          <ul>
          <li><a href="shonen.html" class="entete" title="Shonen">Shônen</a>
            <li><a href="shojo.html" title="Shojo">Shôjo</a></li>
            <li><a href="kodomo.html" title="Kodomo">Kodomo</a></li>
            <li><a href="seinen.html" title="Seinen">Seinen</a></li>
            <li><a href="josei.html" title="Josei">Josei</a></li>
            <li><a href="youngSeinen.html" title="Young Seinen">Young Seinen</a></li> 
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </li>



    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dvdmenu" title="Anime">Anime</a>
      <div class="drop-menu" role="menu">
        <div class="block-1-3">
          <ul>
             <li><a href="test.html" class="entete" title="Shonen">Shônen</a>
            <li><a href="index.php/reports/" title="Shojo">Shôjo</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php/sorties/" title="Kodomo">Kodomo</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php/planning/" title="Seinen">Seinen</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php/a-venir" title="Josei">Josei</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php/agenda/" title="Young Seinen">Young Seinen</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </li>




    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="index.php/univers-jeuxvideo" class="jeuxvid" title="Jeux Video">Video games</a>

      <div class="drop-menu" role="menu">
        <div class="block-1-3">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php/jeuxvideo/" class="entete">All video games</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php/consoles/8">Consoles</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php/developpeurs/">Developpers</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php/editeur/jeux-video">Video games editors</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </li>


    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="index.php/univers-cine-asie" class="asie" title="Cinéma Asie">Asian cinema</a>

      <div class="drop-menu" role="menu">
        <div class="block-1-3">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php/dvds-asie/" class="entete">Every asian movies</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </li>


    </ul>

    </nav>

  </div>


</div><!-- /.container -->
</div><!-- /#header-bottom -->
</header>
    <div id="page">

    <div id="bangeante"><a class="external-link" href="redirection.php?go=574" rel="nofollow" ><img src="http://www.manga-news.com/public/banners/TOYOURETERNITY.jpg" alt="Actualité manga" width="1600" height="1400"/></a></div>

    <div id="global" class="container " >



      <div id="contentWrapper">

          <div id="dummy"></div>




      <div id="content">


        <div class="entryPage" id="annuaire">

 <div id="main">



    <h2 class="entryTitle">Mangas, series :</h2></br>


  <div class="boxed entries large" id="new-volumes">



  </div>
  <div>

  <div id="alphablock"><ul class="alphaLink"><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/" class="selected">#</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/A">A</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/B">B</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/C">C</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/D">D</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/E">E</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/F">F</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/G">G</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/H">H</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/I">I</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/J">J</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/K">K</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/L">L</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/M">M</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/N">N</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/O">O</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/P">P</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/Q">Q</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/R">R</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/S">S</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/T">T</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/U">U</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/V">V</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/W">W</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/X">X</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/Y">Y</a></li><li><a href="http://www.manga-news.com/index.php/series/Z">Z</a></li></ul></div>
<form id="planningFilter" action="" method="get" />


    </form>
    <p id="test"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // declaration            
          // to form the SPARQL query structure by using javascript. The data’s can be retrieved from the online link specified in the where condition           
          $.sparql("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
         .prefix("rdfs", "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#")
         .select(["?label"])
           .where("<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Tim_Berners-Lee>", "rdfs:label", "?label")
         .execute(function success(data) {    //The returned result in JSON format.   
            //To initialize the dropdownlist control with retrieved JSON values.                               
             $('#dropDown').ejDropDownList({
                 dataSource: [data][0],
                //We retrieve the JSON values with label field. So we map the label value to dropdownlist text field.            
                 fields: { text: "label" }
             });

</script>
 <div class="control">
        <div class="ctrllabel"> DropDownList Control Rendered with SPARQL Query </div>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="dropDown" />
    </div>



        <div id="footer">

          <a href="#top" id="top-link"></a>

          <div id="ban970250">
    <ins data-revive-zoneid="23" data-revive-target="_blank" data-revive-id="5180bced55ed2e8ebc8789ceb4c84ee1"></ins>
<script async src="//www.manga-news.com/adservermn/www/delivery/asyncjs.php"></script></div>

<div id="footer-links">
<ul>
  <li><a href="/" title="Accueil">Welcome page</a> | </li>

  <li><a href="index.php/nous" >Who are we ?</a> | </li>
  <li><a href="mailto:Anthonynguyen77@hotmail.fr">Contact us</a></li>

</ul>
</div>





<p class="copyrights">Every datas and illustrations are under © Copyright, they are the propriety of their authors and editors.</p>







<div class="clearer"></div>

<p>
</p>
        </div>

      </div>




    </div> <!--end contentWrapper -->




    </div> <!--end global-->

</div> <!--end page -->










  <script src="js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
      mode : "textareas",
      theme : "advanced",
      editor_selector : "mce",
      plugins : "style",
      theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,separator,undo,redo,separator,cleanup,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,styleselect",
      theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
      theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
      theme_advanced_styles : "Normal=normal;Spoiler=spoiler",
      theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "bottom",
      theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left"
    });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
      mode : "textareas",
      theme : "advanced",
      editor_selector : "mce2",
      theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,separator,undo,redo,separator,cleanup,separator,bullist,numlist",
      theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
      theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
      theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "bottom",
      theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "center"
    });
  </script>


  <script type='text/javascript'><!--//<![CDATA[
    var ox_u = 'http://www.manga-news.com/adservermn/www/delivery/al.php?zoneid=21&target=_blank&layerstyle=simple&align=center&valign=middle&padding=2&closetime=0&padding=2&shifth=0&shiftv=0&closebutton=t&backcolor=FFFFFF&bordercolor=000000';
    if (document.context) ox_u += '&context=' + escape(document.context);
    document.write("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='" + ox_u + "'></scr"+"ipt>");
    //]]>--></script>





<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#comment-form :radio.star').rating();
  });
</script>





<!--

</body>
</html>
```

thank you very much :)

Comment: What does not work? I mean, the idea is to use the JSON data and visualize it in the HTML. There is nothing special to SPARQL.